# Default Level Check setting for command outfile

Tags: ibm-midrange

On IBM i, is it true to say that for any IBM i command that has the OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) parameter, the LVLCHK of the resulted file will always be *NO?

I tried it on a few commands, like DSPOBJD, DSPFD, DSPUSRPRF, all the resulted file has LVLCHK set to *NO.